# Qt 5.0.1 project crashes

Tags: qt

I've got a project using Qt 5.0.2, and my OS is Windows 7 32 bit.
I am working on big project from months and I didn't had any problems with it to now.One of my dialogs, is Print Preview Dialog and the other dialog contains SSN calculation algorithms with line edit. When I put the project on Debug Mode, my Print Preview Dialog works great, I can print everything that I want, but when I start typing something in the SSN line edit, the program total crashes. And reverse, when I put Release Mode, SSN works fine, but when I do click on the "Print" button in the Print Preview Dialog, my program crashes again. Today, I tried to put in some other objects like (buttons, line edits, etc), but the program does not recognize them.For example when I write ui-> ... and I don't get the new objects.

I think that I need to download and install the newest version of Qt (5.1.1), but I don't know, could I change my Project version easy. I am afraid, that nothing will work after this new version install. Please tell me what to do. Should I install the newest version, cause I can't continue my Project.

Comment: please formulate your question to be clearer: leave only isn't working and what you have tried

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no-one can possibly know what's wrong with this guy's setup

Comment: With one word, nothing is working, as i said, program crashes, in Release Mode in one algorithm and in Debug mode on other algorithm. I don't get my new objects in the ui-> ... I think that these problems are enough. And finally, yes, my everything in my program, was working excellent before 2 weeks. Everything just starting crashing randomly, and often. Now this "ui->" -.- Just tell me, will reinstalling Qt will solve my problems. And what is the chance? Thank again.

Comment: Kuba, i don't know what to say. I can't describe my happiness at the moment. Thanks you so much dude! You are solving my second problem already! Everything is working fine ! My Print Preview Dialog (that you've written to me how to make it), and now this full crash. The only problem now is that, i don't get my ui-> objects, i don't know why, i must figure it out. Something with the editor should be. However, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Qt != Qt Creator. The creator is just the IDE. Qt is the framework you're using. Please don't confuse everyone by using the two terms interchangeably.
2. It's trivial to build your project for multiple Qt versions, even for Qt 4 and Qt 5. Qt Creator supports an arbitrary number of Qt installations. You can select what you're building for in the `Projects` pane of Creator. You can then build for whichever kit. Before you do that,

   - set up the newly downloaded version of Qt in Creator
   - set up a *kit* using that Qt version; The kit is a combination of Qt version, compiler, target environment (Desktop in your case), etc.
3. Most likely you have memory bugs in your program. The usual suspect is double destruction of objects caused by giving an automatic (on-the-stack) `QObject`/`QWidget` a parent. You can use Valgrind on Linux to find such issues.
4. To be sure of what's going on, delete the build directory and rebuild your project.
5. Qt Creator version is mostly irrelevant in this discussion. Qt 5.1.1 binaries coincidentally come with Qt Creator 2.8.1, that's just for your convenience. It doesn't mean you can only use creator 2.8.1 with Qt 5.1.1. I'm using it with both Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.1.